# How to change QComboBox QAbstractItemView border radius in Qt Style sheet

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets

[image]

I want the QCombobox to have a round shape similar to the picture above.

[image]

I made it somewhat similar.

[image]

But when I click the QComboBox to check the list, the round shape is not created.

The border is round, but the background doesn't seem to be the case.

```css
QComboBox:editable {
    background-color : red;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border : 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

This is the 3rd photo style sheet. I wrote it for testing.

Comment: Try the solution given in this Qt forum thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/76085/qcombobox-item-list-border-radius. It works for me on Linux/X11, but I can't test on other platforms.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks I solved the problem and it works on windows 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
comboBox_name.view().window().setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
comboBox_name.view().window().setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```